# .Net combobox with data values from one database & value saved in another

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding, combobox

I have one table INVOICEDETAILS that contains a PRODUCTID among other things. I want to create a combobox that gets all possible PRODUCTID values from the INVENTORY table but save the selected value to the INVOICEDETAILS table.

I can fill in the combobox with the INVENTORY values via the DATASOURCE property, but what I can't figure out is how to save the selected combobox value into INVOICEDETAILS. What is the best-practice way of accomplishing this?

I have been able to do this by making a dummy label bound to the INVOICEDETAILS PRODUCTID field and then updating the label TEXT value when the combobox changes, but 1) this seems like a kludge, and 2) the dummy label has to be set to VISIBLE for this to work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you're using for a datasource, the answer differs.  Usually you would use a DataSet as a datasource and handle this by specifying a ValueMember, and then saving that valuemember as part of a general DataSet-saving routine.

Example:

```
private void PopulateComboBox()
{
    DataSet Source = RetrieveDataSet();
    myComboBox.DataSource = Source;
    myComboBox.ValueMember = "MemberColumnName";
}

private void SaveData()
{
    DataSet UpdatedData = GetUpdatedData();  //will put myComboBox.ValueMember into the appropriate column in UpdatedData
    DoDBSave(UpdatedData);  // Will call a serialization routine that knows how to deal with UpdatedData
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I am using a DataSet via a BindingSource. It sounds like there is no automated (eg. connection/ configuration in Visual Studio) to update the INVOICEDETAILS table. It sounds like your solution and Andy's require me to write code to modify the field in the INVOICEDETAILS table and then save the changes. Thanks for the help, I wasn't sure what was possible or standard w/r/t .Net, databinding & comboboxes.

Comment: I'd imagine there's a way to create a data binding object that does this, but it would almost certainly require code in that case as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would just bind the combobox one way, so you can get the values from the inventory table, but I wouldn't use datasource controls or anything to do the save.  I'd just call whatever business object method I have to persist the invoicedetails data, taking the selected combobox value as a parameter.